# How to make some letters in string BOLD

Tags: java, string, fonts

I'm looking for an easy way to make some letters in a label bold.
I have a string like this:

```
String r = "y = "+output0+" "+output1+"sin(x) "+output2+"cos(x)";
```

and a label:

```
Label s = new Label(r);
```

and I need to make the "y" and "sin(x), cos(x)" bold. I tried using HTML, but it didn't work (maybe i was using it wrong). If I set font for that label, then the whole label is bold (including those outputs) which is not what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use html style in JLabels and in some other Java components. If you start your text with `<html>` and end it with `</html>`, the html code in your JLabel will be rendered.

This should resolve your issue:

```
JLabel myLabel = new JLabel(); 
// The following line is required to make this JLabel's text not bold as JLabel's text is bold be default.
myLabel.setFont(myLabel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN)); 
myLabel.setText("<html><strong>y</strong> = " + output0 + " " + output1 + "<strong>sin(x)</strong> " + output2 + "<strong>cos(x)</strong></html>");
```

Comment: I was using Label instead of JLabel, now it works perfectly, thank you very much.

Comment: You shouldn't use [`<b>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b) tags when [`<strong>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong) would make more sense.

Comment: No problem @Jardao. If you were happy with my answer and it worked for you, could you please accept the answer.

Comment: @DermotBlair, You are welcome, I'll give you a +1 now that you include that

Comment: Um... I thought it works, but now if i use JLabel instead of Label, the whole text in that label is bold no matter if i use html or not.

Comment: I have not tested this but I assume your JLabel initialization should be  `new JLabel("<html><strong>y</strong> = " + output0 + " " + output1 + "<strong>sin(x)</strong> " + output2 + "<strong>cos(x)</strong></html>");`

Comment: That is exactly what i need, but for some reason it doesn't really work. I don't know why, but every JLabel i use appears to be bold no matter if i use html, or just inicialize it as `new JLabel("Hello");`

Comment: Try this: `JLabel myLabel = new JLabel(); myLabel.setFont(myLabel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN)); myLabel.setText("<html><strong>y</strong> = " + output0 + " " + output1 + "<strong>sin(x)</strong> " + output2 + "<strong>cos(x)</strong></html>");`

Comment: Sir, you deserve a medal. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try using HTML (you have to start the string with `<html>` and end it with `</html>`):

```
new Jlabel("<html>Normal text. <strong>This is bold.</strong></html>")
```

Explanation! `<html>` tells Java to render HTML (Hyper Text Markup Language), and [`<strong>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong) tells HTML that the text inside is of strong importance, normally represented in bold.

Comment: `<strong>` doesn't tell HTML to do anything. It's a semantic tag that means "this is of strong importance" and the renderer can do what it wants with that; almost always, they bold it, but they could make it upside down if they wanted to.

Comment: Defiantly, as I explained, but same as any other html tag, if `<strong>` would work, then it's better to use then `<b>`